# How to allow selectizeInput in bslib to overlap card?

Tags: css, r, shiny, bslib

The default stylesheets of `bslib` allow for `dateInputs` and other similar kinds of widgets to overlap the boundaries of the `card` containers, but not `select(ize)Inputs` (so far as I can see).

I've tried adjusting the css `position`, `z-index`, and other parameters via `bs_add_rules`() for `.selectize-dropdown` and `.selectize-dropdown-content`, but have had no luck in altering the overlap behavior.  I think I'm missing something simple, or else not understanding the css conflicts.

In short, how can I get `selectizeInput` to behave like `dateInput` with respect to z-indexing (i.e. to overlap the box(es), rather than force an overflow with card-internal scrolling)?

Here's a basic reprex:

```
library(shiny)
library(bslib)

ui <- page_sidebar(
  underline = F,
  theme = bs_theme(
    version = 5,
    font_scale = .8,
    bootswatch = "united",
    base_font = font_google("Roboto"),
    code_font = font_google("JetBrains Mono"),
    heading_font = font_google("Prata")
  ),
  title = "Z-index test",
  sidebar = "",
  card(
    fill = F,
    selectizeInput("test_input", "Letters: ", choices = LETTERS)
  ),
  card(
    fill = F,
    dateInput("test_date", "Dates")
  )
)

shinyApp(ui, function(input, output) {})
```

**Session info:**

```
shiny         1.8.0
bslib         0.6.1
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is solved by changing the css of card and cardbody:

```
library(shiny)
library(bslib)

ui <- page_sidebar(
  underline = F,
  theme = bs_theme(
    version = 5,
    font_scale = .8,
    bootswatch = "united",
    base_font = font_google("Roboto"),
    code_font = font_google("JetBrains Mono"),
    heading_font = font_google("Prata")
  ),
  title = "Z-index test",
  sidebar = "",
  card(
    fill = F,
    style = "position:relative; z-index:1000;",
    selectizeInput("test_input", "Letters: ", choices = LETTERS)
  ),
  card(
    fill = F,
    dateInput("test_date", "Dates")
  ),
  tags$head(tags$style('.card{overflow: visible !important;}'),
            tags$style('.card-body{overflow: visible !important;}'))
)

shinyApp(ui, function(input, output) {})
```